# phonegap release build apk not working in previous Android version - Lollipop

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I'm working on an ionic application with material design.
After taking a release built in PhoneGap and checking it on a mobile, it displays a blank white screen. It's already working in development as a debug APK. I don't know why it's not working on our my environment.

Below is my `index.html`:

```
<!-- script -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ion-md-input/js/ion-md-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ion-floating-menu/dist/ion-floating-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="lib/sweet-alert/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA_rECkai1SfPXFpmSXEqksKQaASuDHbOM&libraries=places&sensor=false"> 
</script>
<script src="lib/angular-google-places-autocomplete/dist/autocomplete.min.js"> 
</script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/service.js"></script>
<script src="js/service2.js"></script>
```

Comment: How did you built your release-app? For instance when I build my ionic-app with android-studio, the device-ready event never fired, but when I build it by using some shell-commands(ionic/cordova build android) "in development-mode", then device-ready is fired.

Comment: I used Phonegap to take release build. Actually i am not using andriod studio and shell-commands. Debug apk works fine but release apk not working in andriod kikat version.

Comment: I have not used phonegap to build my app for years, but there might be a plugin that phonegap does not support and is not built as a result. are all plugins defined in your config.xml file or have you added a plugin afterwards?

Comment: I removed one plugin and its functionality before taking release build. It works fine above andriod kikat version. I need the app to work in kikat version. I actually don't know what is going wrong..